# MYSQL Subquery returns more than 1 row Triggers after update

Tags: mysql, if-statement, triggers

I try to make one triggers to auto change some of my data everything is okay mysql accept my triggers but after that when i try to update on data showing me that error

**Subquery returns more than 1 row**

First my database little huge about this i'm copy here what i select with limit 3

My trigger is

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER test3 AFTER UPDATE ON `coupons_data_result`
BEGIN
DECLARE mac INT default 0;
DECLARE durum INT default 0;
DECLARE ms1 INT default 0;

SET mac =(SELECT match_guess_type_id FROM coupon_rows WHERE match_code=NEW.cpnd_benzersiz);
SET durum =(select cpnd_status FROM matchs_result where cpnd_benzersiz=NEW.cpnd_benzersiz);
SET ms1 =(select cpnd_macsonucu1 FROM coupons_data_result where cpnd_benzersiz=NEW.cpnd_benzersiz);

IF (durum=3) THEN
    IF(mac=1)THEN
        IF(ms=1)THEN
            UPDATE  coupon_rows SET match_result='1' WHERE match_code=NEW.cpnd_benzersiz;
        Else
            UPDATE  coupon_rows SET match_result='0' WHERE match_code=NEW.cpnd_benzersiz;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END IF;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

What i select on my database with limit 3

```
+---------------------+-------------+
| match_guess_type_id | match_code  |
+---------------------+-------------+
|                   3 | 20170130398 |
|                   0 | 20170130399 |
|                   2 | 20170130401 |
+---------------------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

+-------------+----------------+
| cpnd_status | cpnd_benzersiz |
+-------------+----------------+
|           3 | 20170129312    |
|           3 | 20170129313    |
|           3 | 20170129314    |
+-------------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

+-----------------+----------------+
| cpnd_macsonucu1 | cpnd_benzersiz |
+-----------------+----------------+
|               0 | 20170129312    |
|               1 | 20170129313    |
|               1 | 20170129314    |
+-----------------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

End what i try to update list

```
+--------------+-------------+
| match_result | match_code  |
+--------------+-------------+
|            1 | 20170130398 |
|            3 | 20170130399 |
|            3 | 20170130401 |
+--------------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Ps: All match_code and benzersiz is on the table

Comment: There is nothing much to explain here; one of the three subqueries is returning more than one record.  An immediate fix would be to tag `LIMIT 1` to the end of each subquery, but a better long term fix would be to fix the logic of the queries such that the one record you really want gets returned.

Comment: I understood that thank you fixed now. where i set mac it's was returning more that one. Now everything look okay but not working my trigger :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it's one of the below 3 statements that is failing:

```
SET mac =(SELECT match_guess_type_id FROM coupon_rows WHERE match_code=NEW.cpnd_benzersiz);
SET durum =(select cpnd_status FROM matchs_result where cpnd_benzersiz=NEW.cpnd_benzersiz);
SET ms1 =(select cpnd_macsonucu1 FROM coupons_data_result where cpnd_benzersiz=NEW.cpnd_benzersiz);
```

One of the `SELECT` statements is returning more than one row and hence, MySQL can't assign the value. The reason why you can't see the dups in your example is because the rows is limited by 3.

For debugging purpose, I would suggest creating a temp table with 1 column, like

`CREATE TABLE TEMP(error varchar(100));`

And add an error message from inside the trigger if one of those queries return more than one record, e.g.:

```
DECLARE count INT default 0; 
SET count = (SELECT count(*) FROM coupon_rows WHERE match_code=NEW.cpnd_benzersiz);
IF (count > 1) THEN //INSERT into temp with with error message
```

This will give you more info on what's failing. And once it's fixed, you can drop `temp` table and count.

Also, in the trigger, you can use one `IF` with conditions joined with `AND` rather than 3 nested `IFs`, e.g.

`IF (durum=3 AND mac=1 AND ms=1) THEN ..`

Comment: Thanks for advice that help me to find problem also @tim answer help me to fix it but after that i understood i need loop on my trigger